Last PDF in VBA Loop will not InsertPages into combined PDF using VBA and Adobe
I'm writing code to create a report with multiple sections into one PDF. This takes a cover page and inserts a section page and then the report, then it moves to the next section page and report. The code works great until the very last document in the loop. It will never add the last document no matter how many items are in the array. It adds the last section page and the last report does not go into the PDF. If there is (1x) SectionArray doc and (1x) PathArray doc, the SectionArray will get inserted and the PathArray doc won't. If there are 5 documents, all 4 documents will combine with the main PDF and the last one will not. I've tried different PDFs to check if it was security or permission issues. It seems to be a problem with the very last document in the loop. Is there an issue with the loop and Adobe SDK?

I have tried passing (4x) SectionArray/PathArray document pairs and (4x) SectionArray documents get combined, while only (3x) PathArray documents combine into the PDF. The last one returns false.
I've tried passing in different PDFs to rule out security or permission issues. It's always the last document in the loop no matter what documents are chosen. Different PDFs work if put in different orders.
I have tried passing only (1x) SectionArray/PathArray document pair and the SectionArray document inserts fine while the PathArray document returns a false. So, again, it's only the last item in the loop that doesn't get combined.

Not sure what to do. See a modified section of the code for an example of what I'm doing:
    'Cover page location that was already 
    finalFilePath = "FINAL DOCUMENT PATH\Project Name Close-Out Package.pdf"

    'Section page file locations and reports to combine into the final PDF
    'SectionArray will always be the same length as the PathArray
    Dim SectionArray() As String
    SectionArray(0) = "SectionPage/Path/Here"
    SectionArray(1) = "SectionPage/Path/Here"
    SectionArray(2) = "SectionPage/Path/Here"
    Dim PathArray() As String
    PathArray(0) = "Document/Path/Here"
    PathArray(1) = "Document/Path/Here"
    PathArray(2) = "Document/Path/Here"

    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    ok = primaryDoc.Open(finalFilePath)
    

    Dim xcounter As Integer
    xcounter = 0
    For Each L In PathArray
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
        Debug.Print "numPages: " & numPages
        Set sectiondoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        If sectiondoc.Open(SectionArray(xcounter)) Then
            numberOfPagesToInsert = sectiondoc.GetNumPages()
            ok = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sectiondoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Else
            Debug.Print "Could not open file: " & SectionArray(xcounter)
        End If
        sectiondoc.Close
        Set sectiondoc = Nothing
        
        
        numPages2 = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
        Debug.Print "numPages2: " & numPages2
        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        If sourceDoc.Open(PathArray(xcounter)) Then
            Debug.Print PathArray(xcounter)
            Debug.Print "Open Document Succeeded"
            numberOfPagesToInsert2 = sourceDoc.GetNumPages()
            Debug.Print numberOfPagesToInsert2
            If primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages2, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert2, False) Then
                Debug.Print "Inserted Pages: " & ok
            Else
                Debug.Print "Could not add pages: " & PathArray(xcounter)
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Could not open file: " & PathArray(xcounter)
        End If
        
        xcounter = xcounter + 1
    Next L
    
    ok = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, finalFilePath)
    primaryDoc.Close
    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing


"the PathArray document returns a false" where does this occur exactly?

Try adding sourceDoc.close : Set sourceDoc = Nothing before xcounter = xcounter + 1

You can re-arrange your code to remove some of the repeated parts (untested):
Sub ConstData()

    'Cover page location that was already
    Const finalFilePath As String = "FINAL DOCUMENT PATH\Project Name Close-Out Package.pdf"
    Const PDSaveFull = 1
    
    Dim sources, i As Long, pth As String, numPages As Long
    Dim primaryDoc As Object, sourceDoc As Object, numberOfPagesToInsert As Long
    
    'array of alternating pairs of section + document
    sources = Array("SectionPage/Path/Here1", "Document/Path/Here1", _
                    "SectionPage/Path/Here2", "Document/Path/Here2", _
                    "SectionPage/Path/Here3", "Document/Path/Here3")
    
    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    If Not primaryDoc.Open(finalFilePath) Then
        Debug.Print "### Could not open primary doc!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For i = LBound(sources) To UBound(sources)
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
        
        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        pth = sources(i)
        If sourceDoc.Open(pth) Then
            Debug.Print "Inserting from '" & pth & "'"
            numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages()
            If primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False) Then
                Debug.Print , "Inserted " & numberOfPagesToInsert & " pages"
            Else
                Debug.Print , "### Failed insert of " & numberOfPagesToInsert & " pages"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            sourceDoc.Close 'close only if the document could be opened...
        Else
            Debug.Print , "### Could not open file!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
        
    If primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, finalFilePath) Then
        primaryDoc.Close
        Debug.Print "---------Process Complete-------------"
    Else
        Debug.Print "### Failed to save compiled PDF!"
    End If
End Sub


Appreciate the help. I was able to figure it out. The problem was the documents were opened in another section of the code to make a table of contents. That's why the last item was left open and was always un-editable. Appreciate the help!

I was able to figure out the problem. There was a part of the code in the previous section that opened up all the documents to add a table of contents based on their page numbers. I wasn't closing the document, so they must have all been open still. Make sure to close the PDFs after getting information or it will lock the PDF and make it uneditable. Appreciate the help, everyone!
